# mlocate re-index only one folder

Tags: linux, locate

Let's say I changed the contents of one or a small number of folders (added / deleted / renamed files) and want to add them to the `mlocate` index.

What I would like is to:

- Re-index only the specified folder(s), i.e. not the whole root tree (which I think is a default)
- Keep the index for the other parts of the tree intact, i.e. I don't want to end up with an index that contains **only** the specified folder(s)
- Use the default DB file (`/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db`), i.e. not a separate `mlocate` index file

Is this possible in Linux (Xubuntu in my case if that matters)?